# OSX Dashboard widget command line access problem

Tags: javascript, macos, widget, dashboard

I'm trying to access command line from a simple Dashboard Widget on Snow Leopard. My intention is to fill the contents of the widget from a command-line script I call. [This should be possible](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Dashboard_ProgTopics/Articles/CommandLine.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003050-SW1).

I'm calling the script every time the widget is shown using it's onshow callback:

```
if (window.widget) { 
    widget.onshow = onshow; 
} 

function onshow() {
    document.getElementById("mydynamicarea").innerHTML = widget.system("/usr/bin/id -un", null).outputString;
}
```

Above I'm trying to use just a simple command showing my username to test the command-line access. This doesn't work, the widget shows just the static text which I have on the HTML:

```
  <div id="mydynamicarea">No data available</div>
```

The same Javascript works if I use a static string instead of the widget.system call:

```
if (window.widget) { 
    widget.onshow = onshow; 
} 

function onshow() {
    document.getElementById("mydynamicarea").innerHTML = "This text is actually shown on widget";
}
```

When I look at the Console, I can see this error-message:

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'widget.system' [undefined] is not a function.
```

I have configured the command-line access in info.plist:

```
<key>AllowSystem</key>
<true/>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried restarting Daschode after changing the the Info.plst? Dashcode can do crazy things, sometimes.

Comment: I'm testing this by double-clicking the MyWidget.wdgt on Finder and installing it to Dashboard. Thanks for the tip of using Dashcode. The Widget works there! I quess I'll have to reboot OSX to make it work on Dashboard, or is there some way to restart just Dashboard?

Comment: You can kill the Dashboard process with `killall Dock`. It will be restarted automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
killall DashboardClient
```

helped for me

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some bug in Dashboard. I managed to make the Widget work by renaming it. The widget worked just fine in Dashcode before renaming (thanks, Till Theis) and when I installed it from there with another name it worked. That inspired me to just trying to rename it and that worked as well.